# Laravel 7 Vue.js not detected

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm creating a new Laravel project (Laravel 7) and would like to use vue.js as frontend.  I install it via laravel/ui.

The problem is Vue js doesn't seem to load and Vue Devtools showed `vue.js not detected`.
Here are the the blade file and app.js

blade file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='/images/favicon.ico'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/app.css'>

    <title>Conference management</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <section class="header">
        <div class="level-left">
          <div class="level-item">
            <div>
              <p class="title has-text-primary">Conference management</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="level-right">
          <a href="//www.cri.or.th" class="logo">
            <img src="/images/cri_logo_s.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="column"></div>

            <div class="column is-half-table is-two-fifths-desktop">
              include login
              @{{ new Date }}
            </div>

            <div class="column"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <footer class="footer">
        <div class="content has-text-centered">
            &copy; @{{ year }} Organization
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.config.devtools = true;


Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    year: (new Date).getFullYear()
});
```

I ran `npm run dev` successfully and the css and js links are pointed to the correct file.

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you following this tutorial for your project : [Link](https://www.techiediaries.com/laravel/how-to-install-vuejs-in-laravel-6-7-by-example/)

Maybe you forget to install with npm vuejs.

Tell me if you have got again this problem :).

Comment: Thanks Gary Houbre. I did exactly what it said in the link. pretty sure vue.js is installed.

Comment: Do you have a component defined and referenced on the page you are loading?